# Question on the unramified representation

Tags: rt.representation-theory, automorphic-forms, p-adic-groups

$\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}$Let $F$ be a $p$-adic field and $\chi$ be an unramified character of $\GL_1(F)$.

Consider an induced representation $\pi$ of $\GL_2(F)$ induced from the character $\chi|\cdot|^{\frac{1}{2}} \times \chi^{-1}|\cdot|^{\frac{1}{2}}$ of $\GL_1(F) \times \GL_1(F)$. (Here, the induction is the normalized induction.)

Let $\sigma$ be an unramified irreducible constituent of $\pi$. Then I am wondering why $\sigma$ should be an irreducible constituent of $\chi(\det)$? I don't know that how the 'unramified' condition makes it possible.

Comment: What is $\chi(\det(2))$?

Comment: @LSpice, Oh I am sorry! It is $\chi(\det) $!

Comment: $\chi \circ \det$ is 1-dimensional.  $\sigma$ being unramified means it must be trivial on integral units.  Does this help?

Comment: @Kimball, byt $\pi$ have another constituent other than $\chi(\det)$. Why $\sigma$ cannot be a constituent of such another constituent of $\pi$?

Comment: What does constituent mean?  Do you mean subquotient?  The infinite-dimensional one will be ramified.

Comment: @Kimball, Yes! The constituent I mean is a subquotient. “ The infinite-dimensional one will be ramified” is what I am curious. Why does this hold?